How can I copy email from my iPhone when it's offline
I really messed up. My main email account is a Gmail instance operated by my University as a benefit for alumni. In the process of cleaning out the 20,000 mail message "Archived" into the "All Mail" folder by my various iOS devices I ended up deleting the mail from my "Sent Mail" mailbox and all the old mail I still had in my INBOX. I've already contacted my University email team asking if they can restore deleted email but I'm not holding my breath.
What I have now is an iPhone connected to this same Gmail account that has a cached copy of both the INBOX and the "Sent Mail" from before I messed up. So I put it in AirPlane mode and launched Mail. Sure enough the messages are there and not just the headers, every message I clicked on had the full text, but probably not the attachments. As soon as I take this phone out of Airplane mode and connect to the server things will sync and the messages will go poof! I watched it happen on my iPad.
So I'm trying to copy the 200-300 messages in these two mailboxes to a safe location so that I can then reconnect to the server and then restore (re-copy) them to their rightful home. The problem is that with the phone in Airplane mode it'll let me edit the mailbox, select all the messages and then move them to another email account/mailbox, but nothing actually happens because the phone is in Airplane mode (offline).
I've tried turning off mail for the problem account and then turning off airplane mode to allow my other email accounts back online thinking they may sync the offline move. That doesn't happen and when I do that iOS hides the mailboxes for the problematic and now disabled mail account. So I can't move the messages in that mode, since I can't see them.
Is there some way to export the mail or mailboxes to local storage on the iPhone such that I could then get things back online and then re-import them? Is there utility or application that I could use that might help? Keep in mind, the problem gmail account cannot touch the network or communicate with the Gmail server or the messages I'm trying to save go poof.

Back the phone up before you mess around with it any longer.

Excellent detail, and really sorry to hear the nasty predicament you’re in. It might help us help you if you added a summary at the bottom. Which version of Gmail app if any is on the phone? Is this mail account syncing with the native mail app for iOS? Can you borrow an iPad or phone to test things while the main phone is offline? How many backups of this phone exist to iCloud (and is mail part of that backup) and how many backups to a computer exist.

Before I saw these comments I kept trying different things.
Somehow, last night, I was able to move all the mail in the iPhone INBOX to the INBOX of a different (non-Google) IMAP mail account that my phone was also connected to. I just needed to be patient and let the phone catch up.
This did not work for the Sent mail. But, I was able to move the Sent mail on the iPhone to an empty mail folder in the same Gmail account while the phone was offline.
Bothe these things done, I turned off airplane mode and the other INBOX on the iPhone synced and the Sent mail stayed in the empty folder.

FYI - Mac OS 14.5 Sonoma, Mac Mail.app 16.0, iPhone 15 Pro Max running iOS 17.5.1
The Gmail App on the phone is not in the equation - the one time I checked it, it showed the same state as the Gmail web interface on the Mac.

Continuation on follow up on current state:
On the Mac, in Mail.app I was able to then copy all the INBOX mail from the non Gmail IMAP account back to the Gmail account - SUCCESS (partially)
For the Sent mail, I'm in a bit of limbo. The mail is "in" the previously empty folder on the iPhone, but it's not syncing to the Gmail server. It is full messages in the folder on the phone, I can forward them and they show up with full content. They're just not syncing back to the server.
Time to do a backup of the Phone before the Gmail server wakes up and decides that mailbox should be empty.

SUCCESS - after the backup completed I tried one more thing. Using the iOS Mail App, I "moved" all the sent mail that was in a formally empty mailbox in the Gmail account that wasn't syncing to an empty mailbox in my iCloud mail account. It all moved, even attachments. Then on my Mac in the Mail App I scrolled through all the messages to be sure they al loaded and then I did a select-all and drug them to the Sent mailbox of my Gmail account and viola! I now have a repopulated Sent mailbox. What an ordeal! Thanks for all the suggestions and the reference to iMazing, which I purchased and used.

It's a wild guess.
But you can probably try changing the "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" settings in your gmail account on web, by Disabling the IMAP and enabling the POP for all mail.
Then, ideally your emails should not be deleted from your iphone even after connecting to internet until you manually sync the email. You should be able to forward in this situation.
PS: I would suggest testing this with another gmail account first, if it works.
Regards,
Ashwani

I was thinking just change the password so the sync fails, but with this many mails at stake, I can’t suggest any test unless we’re sure of exactly what to change and where OP has the settings configured.

I would recommend an offline backup (both from google and from your device) with imaging to a computer while you wait for support to advise you. While you’re there, you can look at your webmail from a computer to assess options.

https://imazing.com/ (iPhone to a computer)
https://www.tomsguide.com/how-to/how-to-back-up-gmail (To a computer direct from google)

(You might get a 20% discount on iMazing from this link. I’m a happy customer, no benefit to me from this recommendation.)
Ping me in the comments below if you have answers to my clarifying comments on your main post.
